# Compare value in hashmap with string

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I have a hashmap like this:

```
private HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

So, I've set a key in my code. In my case, the value of key may change: if a condition is true, gets some value, if not, it gets other:

```
if (condition.isTrue) myMap.put("keyName", "stringValue");
```

Finally, I want to compare the value of a key in this map with a string:

```
    if (myMap.get("keyName").equals("stringToCompare")) { 
      [... do something ...] 
    }
```

My problem is: Java returns to me a warning message:

*Method invocation 'equals' may produce 'NullPointerException'*

When I run the program, it doesn't work as it should.

Comment: It is saying that as the value is inside a if statement, it may not always have a value for the key. Hence the possible NullPointerException. Can you share what exactly do you mean by "doesn't work as it should".

Comment: "doesn't work as it should" was just a misnomer, the code doesn't work at all

Comment: Avoid NullPointerException by reversing the operand - `if ("stringToCompare".equals(myMap.get("keyName"))) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message says it all:

```
Method invocation 'equals' may produce 'NullPointerException'
```

Which means, when you're applying `equals` on an object that maybe a string, has a possibility to be `null`.

As you're getting an value from the map with key `keyName`, it is not guaranteed to the `equals` method that the `map.get(key)` will give you the object. If the map doesn't contain any value with that key, it will return `null`, thus `NullPointerException` warning.

I hope you got your answer. But about the program that isn't working as expected as you said, provide a minimum reproducible example pointing what is expected, and what are you getting. Then I will update my answer for that part too.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've founded my problem. Now its working :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple methods here

```
1) map.getOrDefault("keyName","").equals("stringToCompare")
2) Objects.deepEquals(map.get("keyName"),"stringToCompare")
3) "stringToCompare".equals(map.get("keyName"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
if(myMap.get("keyName") != null) {
    if(myMap.get("keyName").equals("stringToCompare")) {
        //do something...
    }
}
```